# Protégé Date filter not working

Tags: sparql

I have a simple query with simple results but when I try to apply a filter on the date, I get no results.

Initial query and result :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?projet ?date
   WHERE { teluq:Gilbert_Paquette foaf:pastProject ?projet.
   ?gilbert foaf:familyName ?paquette.
   ?projet db:projectEndDate ?date.
}
```

Results are of the form : "2012-06-30"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date>

but when I add my filter, I get nothing.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?projet ?date
    WHERE { teluq:Gilbert_Paquette foaf:pastProject ?projet.
    ?gilbert foaf:familyName ?paquette.
    ?projet db:projectEndDate ?date.
    FILTER (?date < "2014-11-04"^^xsd:date)
}
```

I'm using Protégé on an imported turtle file.

Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: It would help if you can provide sample data so that we can attempt to reproduce the data.  Does the query work using a SPARQL engine outside of Protege?

Comment: I think that the `<` SPARQL operator is defined for `xsd:dateTime`s, but not for `xsd:date`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works :

```
PREFIX teluq: <http://exemple.teluq.ca/ressources/> 
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?collab ?projet ?date
WHERE { teluq:Gilbert_Paquette foaf:pastProject ?projet.
?gilbert foaf:familyName ?paquette.
?projet db:projectEndDate ?date.
?collab foaf:pastProject ?projet.
FILTER (?date < "2014-11-08"^^xsd:date)
}
ORDER BY ?projet
```

But thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

[§ 17.3 Operator Mapping](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#OperatorMapping) of the  SPARQL 1.1 standard specifies how the < operator is 
defined for SPARQL (modulo operator extensions), and while it defines the behavior on xsd:dateTimes, it doesn't specify anything about xsd:dates, so its quite possible that the filter expression simply returns false.  However, xsd:dates should be comparable using their lexical forms, so you should be able to do

```sql
#-- when ?date is an xsd:date, compare its lexical form with "2014-11-04".
filter (datatype(?date) = xsd:date && str(?date) < "2014-11-04")
```

Comment: @MusicAndCode You should probably post your working query as an answer and mark it as accepted, then.

Comment: This is actually a very valid answer. In my experience, in SPARQL `xsd:date`s have often unpredictable behaviours when filtered.